# Angular2 Http Get Request takes two clicks to change display

Tags: http, angular

Using angular2 taking 2 clicks to show the data from http get request, no errors showing as to why it is taking two clicks to get the data to show, any ideas?:

another.component.ts

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {ImportService} from "./import.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'doclick',
    template: `
        <p>the key: {{showKey}}</p>
        <button (click)="clickme()">click</button>

    `,
    providers: [ImportService]
})


export class AnotherComponent {
    showKey: string;

    constructor(private _httpService: ImportService) {}

    clickme() {
        this._httpService.get_key()
            .subscribe(
                data => this.showKey = JSON.stringify(data),
                error => this.showKey = "problems",
                () => console.log("finished")
            );
    }
}
```

app.ts

```
import {bootstrap} from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {AnotherComponent} from "./another.component";
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "@angular/http";

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `<h1>hello world</h1>
    <doclick></doclick>
    `,
    directives: [AnotherComponent]
})

export class AppComponent {}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

here is the http service:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable() 

export class ImportService {
    constructor(private _http: Http) {}

    get_key() {
        return this._http.get('http://localhost:3000/getpub')
            .map(res => res.json())
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        App
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <app></app>

    <script src="../build/common.js"></script>
    <script src="../build/angular2.js"></script>
    <script src="../build/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tested this before with another app and it worked just fine, if I test a button to change the test as is its fine. However when using this function to do an http get request it requires a 2 clicks to get the result to show on the template, and also even when there is an error. Anyone see something I'm doing wrong here?

my package.json file:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "electron-prebuilt": "^0.37.8",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "typescript": "^1.8.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.12",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.0.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  }
}
```

Comment: looks like problem with change detection. perhaps wrong version of zone.js or something related.

Comment: I've included my package.json file

Comment: What does "and also even when there is an error." mean? (in the last paragraph)

Comment: There is no error, meaning there is no errors showing indicating that something is not working correctly..    The first click around,the value is undefined, "this.pubKey"

Comment: It has something to be in the http part of things, because this is where the value doesn't adjust to the received data.

Comment: It's like lagging, seems like it sets the value, and when I click again it shows the value from before. Click1: "" actual value: "key1", Click2: "key1" actualy value: "key2", Click3: "key2" actualy value "key3"